# Java equivalent of batch pause?

Tags: java, equivalent

I am using the following code to simulate a clear screen:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {System.out.println();}
```

My problem is is that when I write something on the screen and then it goes back to where this code is, the text written is gone.

I was wondering if there is anything like the pause command in batch files to make it so you can read the screen and then press any button to do the clear screen simulation.

For example:

```
    :go                                                                               
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {System.out.println();}
    int i=0;
    i++;
    System.out.println("first");
    if (i=>5)
    {System.out.println("second");}
    continue go;
```

I want to see both first and second then press a button and continue the process.

Comment: A more practical approach (at least under Unix-ish operating systems) might be to pipe the output into less who will page the output, but also allow to scroll back and search.  You could also write a class that extends PrintStream implementing paging, and send your output to that one instead of to System.out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a pause, you can use Thread.sleep(number of milliseconds).

If you want to wait on a user action, you could do System.in.read(); This will wait for Enter from the user.

Comment: I want the wait on user input approach.

Comment: Yup,this works. I just had to throw some exceptions.